# BroadcastRecevier disabled after device lock/sleep for a while

Tags: android

the guestion i would like to ask is that :After the android device locked for a while my boradcastreveiver wouldn't work 
I resisted it on onStart

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    setBroadcastReceiverAction();
    super.onStart();
}
```

And unregister it on onDestroy

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterBroadcastReceiver();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Notice that everything work perfectly fine before the deceive lock for a longtime, even the device lock for 1/2 minutes. But if i lock the device for like 1 hour, the problem came out

Is there anyway to preventing this happen?

Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Do you want your broadcast receiver to work when it's locked or are you having problems with it after it returns from the lock period?

Answer (score 1):

You should acquire WakeLock to make your broadcast receiver run.

in your boradcast receiver `onReceive()` method acquire a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK and before the `onReceive()` finish release that lock.